# Void Pointers In C

Tags: c, pointers, char, int, void-pointers

I'm beginner in C Programming and Now learning concepts of Pointers. Here's my code -->>

```
`#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {  
    char t='s';
    int a=10;
    float s=89;
    void *ptr;

    ptr =&s;
    printf("%c\t",*((char*)ptr));
    printf("%d\t",*((int*)ptr));
    printf("%f\t",*((float*)ptr));
    return 0;
  }`
```

My question is When I deferenced a void pointer which points to the Floating Point number into Char then why the output is Blank Space and for Integer it is 1118961664. I wish to know that what's going on in the Byte Level and Is it depends on Alignment of Bytes and Architecture!!

Comment: "I wish to know that what's going on in the Byte Level". The thing that's going on is called **Undefined Behavior** and you don't start your learning with this thing.

Comment: @n.m. upvoted, although I do think that wanting to know how things are implemented (possibly) is natural and positive.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes it is natural. Doesn't mean it's the right thing to do.

Comment: Sorry but What do you mean by "You don't start your learning with this thing " . Actually I'm not start learning direct from Undefined Behavior. I know What is void pointer and What's the correct way to deferenced it but I'm curious to know What exactly is this Undefined Behavior !! and Why my code leads to Undefined Behavior. and I'm glad that fedemp answered exactly what I asked .. @n.m.

Comment: "What exactly is this Undefined Behavior". I recommend using a Web search for this one. "Why my code leads to Undefined Behavior". You can cast an object pointer to `void*` and then *back to the original type* only. Cast it to a different type, and your program has UB.

Comment: _undefined behavior_: A good description (one that has passed the test of time)... ***[nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)***.  The C specification includes many descriptions (i.e., definitions) of what happens when the rules are followed, but very little is written about what happens when they are not.  That is why _the thing that happens when the rules are not followed_ is referred to as _undefined_ behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often, the `float s` variable is 4 bytes long and its value (89) is represented in IEEE 754 format. For simplicity, let's assume this.

The first printf (char) will use the first byte of the original float variable `s` (because one C char = 1 byte). Here the first byte means the byte located in the lowest memory position of the 4 bytes of `float s`. Yes, this is dependent on the machine's byte alignment. The output is blank most likely because the first byte corresponds to an ascii control charater (for example 0).

The second printf, assuming that an int is 4-bytes long in your machine/compiler, will take the same 4 bytes as the third printf but will print them as an integer (note the difference between integers and IEEE 754 floating point numbers). It turns out that the IEEE 754 representation of 89 corresponds to a "1118961664" integer. This will also be dependent on byte alignment.

The third printf is doing the right thing, it will use the bytes where s's value (89) is stored, and interpret them as a floating point number. It should print 89.0. This does not depend on byte alignment.

If the size or representation of floats were different the details would change (how many bytes come from where, and what number is printed by the second printf) but the behavior would be similar. Note also that in principle the first two printf calls have undefined behavior.

Comment: Aha, regarding the size and representation of `float s`, it should say "on most systems" or "most likely". It turns out that IEEE 764 is specified in an "optional annex" of the C standard. See [Wikipedia, C basic types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types) for details. Curious to know if there's any compiler out there that uses a different representation for single-precision floating point variables.

Answer (score 0):

float numbers (that is of type float) occupy 4 bytes. In this expression `*((char*)ptr))` the first byte of s is interpretated as a character. In expression `*((int*)ptr))` all four bytes of s are interpretated as an integer provided that sizeof( int ) equal to 4.

As internal representation of float and int are different you get different vresults.

Comment: @Chrono Kitsune When i said about floats I meant objects of type float. You are using constant of type double. doubles and floats have different sizes.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Can you show me where in the specification it says that floats are 4 bytes?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune `2.0` is `double` not `float`

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum AFAIK the float type matches the IEC 60559 single format and if I am not mistaken it fit in 4 bytes..

Comment: Can you show me where it says that in the specification?

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum There are three binary floating-point basic formats (encoded with 32, 64 or 128 bits) in IEEE 754

Comment: The point behind the question asked by @Benjamin is the fact that ISO C does not require a specific format for floating-point. It encourages the usage of IEC 60559 in Annex F, stating that an implementation conforming to that standard may define `__STDC_IEC_559__`. Implementations need not define that macro, whether they conform to the specifications in Annex F or not, but it will only be defined by implementations that conform. In other words, there is no guarantee IEC 60559 is even being used. It could be sheer coincidence that the values match for that number on that platform.